# Keras model only working with Sigmoid activation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I'm building a Keras model to categorise data into one of 9 categories. The issue is it will only work with a Sigmoid activation which is designed for binary outputs, other activations result in 0 accuracy. What would I need to change for it to classify into each of the labels?

```
#Reshape data to add new dimension
X_train = X_train.reshape((100, 150, 1)) 
Y_train = X_train.reshape((100, 1, 1)) 
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv1d(1, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(None, 1))) 
model.add(Dense(1)) 
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) 

model.compile(loss='categorical_hinge', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(x=X_train,y=Y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=20)
```

Comment: For the next time, please do spend a minute to learn how to properly format your code (done it for you this time); also, is `Y_train = X_train.reshape((100, 1, 1)) ` a typo or an actual mistake (should be `Y_train.reshape((100, 1, 1))`)? And are your `Y` data one-hot encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single-unit dense layer is not what we use in the case of multi-class classification; you should first ensure that your `Y` data are one-hot encoded - if not, you can make them so using Keras utility functions:

```
num_classes=9
Y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
```

and then change your last layer to:

```
model.add(Dense(num_classes)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Also, if you don't have any specific reasons to use the categorical Hinge loss, I would suggest starting with `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` in your model compilation.

That said, your model seems too simple, and you may want to try adding some more layers...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, still very new to machine learning. I'll add layers to it soon, I was just trying to get an initial model working.

Comment: @desertnaught Thanks, that worked, but I'm now getting "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have shape (None, 9) but got array with shape (9,1). Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: @JohnWills Please open a new question for any issues different from the initial one